# Add html tag to result of variable jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

in this code is what I want to achieve. The part I'm focusing is the

```
'<span class="chosen">' + title + changed + '</span>';
```

of course it is bad written because `<span></span>` won't be showed as html tags but text.

The code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('.variations-table .select-option a').click(function () {
        var title = $('.variations-table td label').text() + (' Chosen: ');
        var change = $(this).attr("title");
        var phrase = '<span class="chosen">' + title + change + '</span>';
        $('.main-image h5').text(phrase);
    })
});
```

How should I change the code to have the `<span>` tag passed as an html tag?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well use `html()` ..instead of `text()`.

```
 var phrase =$('<span />',{class:"chosen",text:title + change});
 $('.main-image h5').html(phrase);
```

Answer (score 2):

change line

```
$('.main-image h5').text(phrase);
```

to

```
$('.main-image h5').html(phrase);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.main-image h5').html(phrase);
```

`.html()` takes everything inside it as HTML. Even simple text.

`.text()` sets the text property of the element.

similary `.val()` is to be used with setting the "value" property of element.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `text(phrase)` use `html(phrase)`